# Close popups at logout

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm trying to get all popups to close when a logout is done.  Logout is a servlet.  There are many different popups that are opened in this application.  Is there any way to do this?  I think I need to write a program that stores a handle of the popup window.  Does this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the `windowObjectReference` that [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) returns and use [`window.close`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.close):

```
var foo = window.open(…);

foo.close();
```

This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method.